Error when launching Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda
I have installed Anaconda and am getting this error when launching Jupyter Notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in from notebook.app import main
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\app.py", line 12, in from jupyter_server.base.handlers import JupyterHandler
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\base\handlers.py", line 36, in from jupyter_server.utils import (File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\utils.py", line 28, in from jupyter_core.utils import ensure_async as _ensure_async
ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_async' from 'jupyter_core.utils' (C:\Users\rnarasimhappa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jupyter_core\utils\__init__.py)

Did not do anything except install Python and Anaconda. Getting this error from the start.
I did have Anaconda some time ago and had uninstalled it.

@LUKER Thanks for your edit, the thoroughness of which I found improveable. The edit was helpful. Your comment is not. I recommend to delete it.
